# Verify Opensea NFT ownership via API

Tags: nft, opensea

If I make an NFT purchasable on my store on opensea and somebody purchases that item, is there a way for me to build a website where somebody can retrieve services based on providing proof that they own the NFT that I sold on opensea?

##### Workflow

- I sell NFT x
- User y buys NFT x
- User y goes onto my website
- User y would like to use a service granted to them because they are the owner of NFT x

  - This is the crucial point, here I would like to verify that they really are the owner of the NFT

Does opensea provide any mechanism to make that verification possible via an API for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [opensea api docs -> asset model](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/asset-object) and than owner, this should work.

But for the prove you need them to sign with wallet, metamask?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the token & NFT ownership for any address on  Bitquery's Explorer.  Here's an example: https://explorer.bitquery.io/ethereum/address/0xaba7161a7fb69c88e16ed9f455ce62b791ee4d03

You can also use their NFT APIs to get detailed info on ownership
https://ide.bitquery.io/NFT-Ownership